# Start self-contained .net6 build exe as service on Raspbian System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/proc/1/task/1/fdinfo' is denied

Tags: linux, .net-core, hosting, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have .NET 6.0 self-contained build for arm-32 and want to run it on my Pi server as service. The build runs when I do it manually by running ./AppName inside deployment folder. As soon as I try to start it as systemd service it throws UnauthorizedAccessException on path /proc/1/task/fdinfo [image]

the fdinfo file has those permissions dr-xr-xr-x

my linux service is simple

```
[Unit]
Description=Kiai Web Application

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/kiai/Kiai

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**please help with any ideas what could be causing problems or done around it ?**

Comment: i have the same issue when running in a AWS EC2 container

Comment: Did you find a root cause or solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was solved by adding

```
WorkingDirectory=/home
```

to the `[Service]` section.

**P.S.**

`UnauthorizedAccessException` on path `/proc/1/task/fdinfo` is thrown when WorkingDirectory is '/'.